# Close file transfer tabs in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have several tabs open in "File Transfer" from different previous connections.

How can I close unused connection tabs? I can only hide the whole "File Transfer" window but not separate tabs.

PhpStorm version is 2021.3.1

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a regression in 2020.3, one just can't close tabs in the File Transfer tool window any longer.

Have filed it as [WI-65100](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-65100)

Thank you for noticing!